# (Win7/Putty) How to use MySQL Workbench to connect to a DB server which is only accessible after ssh'ing to a jump server

Tags: ssh, windows-7, proxy, mysql-workbench, putty

Friends,

I have been given access to a database server that can only be accessed after ssh'ing into another linux server.
Once I get on this linux server, then I am able to use the command-line mysql client to do a remote connection to the db server.

I would like to be able to use MySQL Workbench ( or another windows client ) to be able to have a GUI interface.

I have putty, and played around with the proxy options, but to no effect.

Any help or pointers in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL Workbench supports SSH connections. This way you can use a jump server via SSH and connect from there to your real server. Just select the "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" connection type when you create a new connection. In [my tutorial video in the MySQL channel on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY&list=PLWx5a9Tn2EvH0q2WXpUBqptxi5640qk9O), about connection creation and troubleshooting, I show (among other things) how to set up such an SSH connection.

Comment: How to do that behind a proxy?